# horrible vs terrible

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between “horrify” and “terrify”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/what-is-the-difference-between-horrify-and-terrify)

Since I am not a native English speaker, I always have trouble figuring out when to use "horrible" instead of "terrible" in both spoken and written English.

According to [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.wordnik.com/words/horrible), *Horrible* means:

> adj. Arousing or tending to arouse horror; dreadful: "War is beyond all words horrible” (Winston S. Churchill).
>       adj. Very unpleasant; disagreeable.

and [Terrible](http://www.wordnik.com/words/terrible) means:

> adj. Causing great fear or alarm; dreadful: a terrible bolt of lightning; a terrible curse.
>       adj. Extremely formidable: terrible responsibilities.
>       adj. Extreme in extent or degree; intense: "the life for which he had paid so terrible a price” (Leslie Fiedler).
>       adj. Unpleasant; disagreeable: had a terrible time at the party; terrible food.
>       adj. Very bad: a terrible actor.

Since their secondary meaning is *Unpleasant, disagreeable*, are there any rules around when these words should be used, or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “horrify” and “terrify”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/what-is-the-difference-between-horrify-and-terrify)

Answer (score 8):

In everyday informal discourse, spoken or written, the words are interchangeable: neither means much of anything beyond "very bad". If someone says to you "Bob's presentation was terrible" you may with perfect propriety respond "Yeah, really horrible."

In more careful usage the two words bear very different different meanings. These reflect the respective first definitions you quote from AHD; see also the discussion of the associated verb forms at the link provided by ЯegDwight in his comment to your question. Briefly:

- *horrible* speaks to the sense of outrage which an act or event arouses: the act transgresses ordinary rational or natural or moral boundaries. Hitler's final solution and Lovecraft's Ancient Ones are *horrible*.
- *terrible* speaks to the sense of dread which an act or event arouses: the act is a sign or a warning of what may come to pass. Tamerlane's conquests and the Lisbon Earthquake of 1755 are *terrible*.

Of course an act or event may be both horrible *and* terrible; but the words address different aspects.

Comment: In the SOng of Solomon (AV) a beautiful woman is described as *terrible as an amrny with banners*; modern translations prefer something like *majestic*.

Comment: @TimLymington  But see [here](http://bible.org/download/netbible/ondemand/bybook/sos.pdf), p. 1251. Why we don't do translation or litcrit.

Comment: Entirely agree that on Translation.SE my point would be out of place.  But here, I don't believe anybody interested in the history of *terrible* can ignore it. (OP may not be, of course, which is why this is a comment not an answer).

Comment: @TimLymington  Quite so. But James' translators worked in a tradition which identified the Song's beloved with the Church, so it's the Church which is metaphorically both a beautiful woman and "terrible".